# Apache is slower on other comptuer in network than on localhost

Tags: php, windows, apache, networking

I have few computers connected into network. There's a server inside that network which hosts WAMP - Apache + PHP + MySQl. There is Windows 7 x32 Pro installed on it. I can ping that server from my wireless connected server, all pings are 1ms.
What is interesting, when I browse my web application on server itselft, it loads in the blink of eye. I can surf subpages like they were images which I'm just switching.

However on the other computers it works slower. It's not tragic, but noticeably slower. In some cases browser shows "Waiting on..." which takes one or two seconds, and this is the most painful.

I figured out that it is much faster to use application on server while I'm connected via remote desktop, than on any other computer. That would be awesome if I could get the same effect on them.

What can I do in that situation?

Comment: This might be better served on Superuser rather than SO.

Comment: @Fluffeh thank you for the notice, i'm new here :-)

Comment: Yup, saw that. The URL is http://superuser.com/ Stackoverflow is more of a "here is my code, what's wrong...?" type site :)